# Setting logic within servlet and showing results in android

Tags: android, servlets

I was wandering if there is an easy way to access a servlet which contains logic to jumble a word. I have the logic to jumble a word and would like to put this within a servlet.

I already have Tomcat set up on eclipse.

Within the android application will be an Onclick method and when clicked will jumble the word through the servlet. I have looked at HttpConnection but not sure how to implement this easily.

Any ideas on how to do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Servlets are able to execute some Java code based on a specific HTTP request URL. You just need to map the servlet class in webapplication's `web.xml` file on a certain `<url-pattern>` (or when you're already running a Servlet 3.0 capable container, using the `@WebServlet` annotation). A kickoff example can be found in the [servlets info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info).

Assuming that the servlet runs at http://example.com/context/yourservlet and returns the `String` result as plaintext like follows:

```
// ...
response.setContentType("text/plain");
response.setContentEncoding("UTF-8");
response.getWriter().write(word);
```

All you need to do is to execute the HTTP request and obtain the HTTP response programmatically. Here's a basic kickoff example using Android's builtin [HttpClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html) API (all obvious exception and resource handling aside):

```
String url = "http://example.com/context/yourservlet";
InputStream input = new DefaultHttpClient().execute(new HttpGet(url)).getEntity().getContent();
String word = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input, "UTF-8")).readLine();
// ...
```

Comment: This answer is pretty good; I'm adding this just in case you are new to android: ensure you have added the internet permission to the manifest before attempting this.

Comment: @BalusC, thanks this is very helpful. But how can I add the HttpClient API to a button which would display the string retrieved in a textview. Thanks

Comment: You're welcome. That's a different question. Please press `Ask Question` on the right top.

Comment: ok sorry, but it does say in the question that the android contains an onClick method and when clicked will jumble the word through the servlet. Shall I open another question for this?

Comment: Sorry, I understood that you've already implemented the other trivial steps. Executing arbitrary Java code on click of a button and displaying arbitrary String in the UI has not much to do with HTTP servlet interaction.

Comment: Ok, so it's not possible to put a jumble word algorithm within a servlet and call that from an onClick button in android. To display the word in a textview?

Comment: I didn't said that..? It's definitely possible, I've even posted an answer how to interact with the servlet. Just execute the 2nd code snippet on click of the button and display the `word` in the UI.